# How to do a "sync" in Perforce P4V client

Tags: synchronization, perforce, revert, p4v

Suppose I have the following structure, already in Perforce:

`//path/to/playground/code/`

And locally I have:

`c:\project\path\to\playground\code\`

After making some changes in the code folder locally, I decided it's no good, and would like to start from the latest code base in depot.

So in Windows Explorer, I renamed `code\` to `code_NG\`
(Yes, I'm aware that I can do a revert, but I'd like to keep the local changes for reference, at least for now.)

**Question**: How do I get a fresh new copy of the `code\` folder from depot?

I've found there's a [p4 command](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2953) called `sync`. But how do I do it in Perforce P4V client?

I come from a SVN background, and this is equivalent of doing a svn update, which downloads all the missing local files from the server.

Comment: FYI for the future, a really handy feature is being able to "shelve" your work on the server before reverting it in your workspace -- later you can "unshelve" to get it back.  The advantage of doing it this way is that it's backed up on the server, and it keeps track of what version you were working on so you can merge in newer changes if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In P4V, choose `Get Revision...`.

Then, since you've re-arranged your local filesystem, and hence your local `code` folder doesn't match the state that the server has recorded, check the `Force Operation` checkbox to ensure that the server will deliver you **all** the files, even the ones that it thinks you already have on your workstation.

Comment: I've verified this works, and the corresponding p4 command is: `p4 sync -f c:\project\path\to\playground\code\...#head`